# Can a type specifier, specify equality to an arbitrary value?

Tags: common-lisp

Common Lisp type specifiers seem to be quite flexible, though I haven't seen anything to indicate they can be an arbitrary predicate (understandable if not, because then type checking would be undecidable in the general case). But can they specify equality to an arbitrary value?

An integer? I think so; `(integer 42 42)` should cover that.

The string `"foo"`?

The symbol `'foo`?

The symbol that was obtained by `(defconstant foo (gensym))`?

If so, what's the syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put any predicate you want under a [`SATISFIES`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_satisf.htm) type.

```
(defun squarep (rect)
  (= (height rect) 
     (width rect)))

(deftype square () '(satisfies squarep))
```

Those types are unlikely to be verified at compile-time.
You would need to use such a type for declaring that a variable is always equal to a given string value, or any other complex data.

For values that are comparable with `EQL`, you can use the [`EQL`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/CLHS/Body/t_eql.htm#eql) or [`MEMBER`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/CLHS/Body/t_member.htm) type specifiers.

```
(deftype foo-symbol () '(eql foo))
(deftype states () '(member :ready :working :error))
```

Constants are compared by identity, you could define:

```
(defconstant +foo+ (gensym))
(deftype foo-constant () `(eql ,+foo+))
```